# Windows NT token with ADFS to get Remote user Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity, adfs

I created a ADFS windows NT enabled tokenapp
Configured IIS 7 to enabled windows NT token in authentication  and reply url as https://adfsweb.treyresearch.net/tokenapp

I added this app into the adfsresource application as Windows NT token based application.

Using this web.config file (http://blogs.technet.com/b/adfs_documentation/archive/2006/08/03/444865.aspx#DSDOC_BKMK_667328988_f5db_446a_9261_00b4)

The default.aspx.cs as below.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Security.Principal;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        WindowsIdentity i = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        IdentityReferenceCollection irc = i.Groups;

        foreach (IdentityReference ir in irc)
        {
            Label2.Text += ir.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).Value.ToString() + "; ";

        }

    }
}
```

It works as long as I log in from adfsresources domain with treyresearch,net user.

If I use this tokenappp url from adatum.com domain I get a error, and on event log of adfsresource server i have this error:

```
Event code: 4011 
Event message: An unhandled access exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/29/2011 7:20:26 PM 
Event time (UTC): 11/30/2011 1:20:26 AM 
Event ID: ac49318023ee4ba4ab7ab6e0bca78522 
Event sequence: 5 
Event occurrence: 2 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/adfs-1-129670890061718750 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /adfs 
    Application Path: C:\Windows\SystemData\ADFS\sts\ 
    Machine name: ADFSRESOURCE 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 1892 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://adfsresource.treyresearch.net:443/adfs/ls/clientlogon.aspx 
    Request path: /adfs/ls/clientlogon.aspx 
    User host address: 192.168.10.133 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Custom event details:
```

Does this means that I need to have Windows trust on top of ADFS trust to be using windows NT token for remote domains? if so there is no point in having ADFS trust, if i also need to have windows domain trust.

I can get my claim app to work correctly from remote domain, but I added this new tokenapp after all the trust policy export import was completed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731103%28WS.10%29.aspx

I have also followed and verified this info below
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734929%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of warning - that article that you reference was written in 2006 and talks about web agents - in other words it's ADFS 1.

ADFS 2 is pretty much a new product. It came out in 2010 and no longer has the concept of agents.

The ADFS "feature" that comes standard with Windows Server 2008 is 1 not 2. You have to download 2 and install it.

[Appendix A: Reviewing AD FS 2.0 Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678034%28WS.10%29.aspx) states "AD FS 2.0 does not support Windows NT token–based applications."

It does, however, support C2WTS (Claims to Windows Token Service).

Comment: i do have ADFS 1.0 installed and that is what i am working with

Comment: OK - got confused because you tagged it as adfs 2. Out of interest, why did you install adfs 1 rather than adfs 2? Was it because of the NT token service?

Comment: i am new to adfs so i thought what came with server 2008 was adfs's up to date version

Comment: Personally, if there's no reason to use adfs 1, I would uninstall it and install adfs 2.0. The link is: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10909. There's a link at the bottom of the page to the Content Map which contains a ton of useful information.

Comment: but isn't Nt toekn not supported on adfs 2.0

Comment: According to the documentation, it's not supported. If it's a must-have, then you'll have to go with ADFS 1.0. Did you have a look at C2WTS? This article might help ? http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/2010/10/15/access-owa-with-adfs.html

Comment: that is a very nice link you had,but i would not be able to use C2WTS for a remote user correct unless i create a id for him in my domain and map it to his domain?

Comment: Haven't used C2WTS for a while but yes you need to make what they call a "shadow account". Google on that.